# Main Controller Issues

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have no idea why but I uploaded a fresh version of CI and my main controller isn't working and not sure why.

http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager

Edit: Any ideas?

Edit 2:

Controller: (kowmanager.php)

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Kowmanager extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('tank_auth');
    parent::__construct();

}

function index()
{
    if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
        redirect('/auth/login/');
    } else {
        $data['user_id']    = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
        $data['username']   = $this->tank_auth->get_username();
        $this->load->view('welcome', $data);
    }
}

}

/* End of file kowmanager.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/kowmanager.php */
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

### Canonicalize codeigniter URLs

# If your default controller is something other than
# "welcome" you should probably change this
RewriteRule ^(kowmanager(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]


# Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Enforce www
# If you have subdomains, you can add them to 
# the list using the "|" (OR) regex operator
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|subdomain) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]

# Enforce NO www
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]

###

# Removes access to the system folder by users.
# Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
# previously this would not have been possible.
# 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

# Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
# such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
# request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

# Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

Config

http://pastebin.com/9ZCpQNJj

Edit:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Kowmanager extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('tank_auth');
    $this->load->library('template');
    echo CI_VERSION;

}

function index()
{
    if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
        redirect('/auth/login/');
    } else {
        $data['user_id']    = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
        $data['username']   = $this->tank_auth->get_username();
        $this->load->view('welcome', $data);
    }
}

}

/* End of file kowmanager.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/kowmanager.php */
```

Comment: Can you provide the steps you've taken to debug the issue?

Comment: http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/index.php/kowmanager produces Message: Undefined property: Kowmanager::$load... Looks like your class has errors

Comment: But it shouldn't have /index.php/kowmanager it should just be /kowmanager

Comment: Yes, I read. What I point out is that what you believe is a redirection error seems to be something completely different.

Comment: What do you mean? What could be the problem.

Comment: Let's see what `kowmanager.php` contains - post the entire thing. It also looks like you *still* have not set an encryption key so you can use the session class, so don't forget to do that. However, I don't think these errors are related.

Comment: Controller looks fine, are you using 2.X system files? How to check: `echo CI_VERSION;` - still I don't think it's related to your 404, let's see the .htaccess as well (*your* file, not the one in the link). Seeing `config.php` would help too. ** And please, set an encryption key so we can cross that off the list. **

Comment: well I'm post those files with another edit but as far as I understand its just a 32 long string of uppercase and lowercase characaters. so it could be helloThisIsMyEncryptionKey2334  but 32 characters long? Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: you must have: `public function __construct()
{parent::__construct();`...

Comment: @Alfonso: Nice catch, I didn't notice it. That definitely solves one issue.

Comment: If your talking about the kowmanager controller that didn't fix it

Comment: I updated my controller to show my new code.

Comment: For your key. http://www.freepasswordgenerator.com/, default settings, lengt 32

Comment: What about for my issue I'm still having though with the 404 error.

Comment: Also I have fixed the problem with the encryption key issue and am connecting to my database however I'm getting this which I shouldn't be getting. I thought I should be getting the welcome message since its still the default. http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com

Comment: As @Wesley says, put `echo CI_VERSION;` affter `parent::__construct();` and tell us what happens

Comment: If you can send me an email with a more direct line of contact and I can show you more in depth code and show you what's going on. my email is xtremer360@yahoo.com

Comment: I figured out one issue why it wasn't echoing because I didn't have the parent::__constrcut(); as the first line inside of the function. So now it echos 2.02 and I've updated my question with a new edit of newest code.

Comment: I still have one odd error though. http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager  and this is what should ultimately load when that first link opens http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/auth/login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Works great kind of.  http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager BUT on the main page http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com the part that is after the .com should be attached to the kowmanager.

Comment: But should I have that same htaccess for the public_html directory AND for the application directory?

Comment: In application directory `Deny from all`

Comment: What about the issue above that.

Answer (score 3):

This is a server 404, not a Codeigniter one - so it's got nothing to do with CI, or your CI configuration.

You must have an issue with your `.htaccess` file, make sure that you are routing all appropriate requests through `index.php`.

If this is supposed to be your default controller, then you have another issue when I view http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com:

> An Error Was Encountered
>
> In order to use the Session class you are required to set an
>   encryption key in your config file.

Self-explanatory I hope.

---

> I used this http://farinspace.com/codeigniter-htaccess-file to make my htacess file

I'm not sure if all this is necessary, but did you read this part?

```
# If your default controller is something other than
# "welcome" you should probably change this
RewriteRule ^(welcome(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

> as far as the encryption key is self explanatory but not sure what to put for it.

I think you need to get familiar with the [docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/), it sounds like you are not making any effort yourself. In fact, the encryption key information is thoroughly covered right in the comments in config file itself.

Comment: I used this http://www.farinspace.com/codeigniter-htaccess-file/ to make my htacess file and changed the config['index_page'] to empty string and as far as the encryption key is self explanatory but not sure what to put for it.

Comment: I changed it to RewriteRule ^(kowmanager(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]    and it still is the same error.